# get access for multiple creditals calendar

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api

Here is my code,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
# Copyright 2012 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

import httplib2
import sys

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenRefreshError
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.tools import run

# For this example, the client id and client secret are command-line arguments.
client_id = '902453498010-6j3sgj6uccrhbhue6aaeg032gssw07g46.apps.googleusercontent.com'
client_secret = 'kbiToYcPCzZGvH3UqhZzuhB6'

# The scope URL for read/write access to a user's calendar data
scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'

# Create a flow object. This object holds the client_id, client_secret, and
# scope. It assists with OAuth 2.0 steps to get user authorization and
# credentials.
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id, client_secret, scope)

def main(filename):

  # Create a Storage object. This object holds the credentials that your
  # application needs to authorize access to the user's data. The name of the
  # credentials file is provided. If the file does not exist, it is
  # created. This object can only hold credentials for a single user, so
  # as-written, this script can only handle a single user.
  storage = Storage(filename)

  # The get() function returns the credentials for the Storage object. If no
  # credentials were found, None is returned.
  credentials = storage.get()


  # If no credentials are found or the credentials are invalid due to
  # expiration, new credentials need to be obtained from the authorization
  # server. The oauth2client.tools.run() function attempts to open an
  # authorization server page in your default web browser. The server
  # asks the user to grant your application access to the user's data.
  # If the user grants access, the run() function returns new credentials.
  # The new credentials are also stored in the supplied Storage object,
  # which updates the credentials.dat file.
  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run(flow, storage)

  # Create an httplib2.Http object to handle our HTTP requests, and authorize it
  # using the credentials.authorize() function.
  http = httplib2.Http()
  http = credentials.authorize(http)

  # The apiclient.discovery.build() function returns an instance of an API service
  # object can be used to make API calls. The object is constructed with
  # methods specific to the calendar API. The arguments provided are:
  #   name of the API ('calendar')
  #   version of the API you are using ('v3')
  #   authorized httplib2.Http() object that can be used for API calls
  service = build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)

  try:

    # The Calendar API's events().list method returns paginated results, so we
    # have to execute the request in a paging loop. First, build the
    # request object. The arguments provided are:
    #   primary calendar for user
    request = service.events().list(calendarId='primary')
    # Loop until all pages have been processed.
    while request != None:
      # Get the next page.
      response = request.execute()
      # Accessing the response like a dict object with an 'items' key
      # returns a list of item objects (events).
      for event in response.get('items', []):
        # The event object is a dict object with a 'summary' key.
        print repr(event.get('summary', 'NO SUMMARY')) + '\n'
      # Get the next request object by passing the previous request object to
      # the list_next method.
      request = service.events().list_next(request, response)

  except AccessTokenRefreshError:
    # The AccessTokenRefreshError exception is raised if the credentials
    # have been revoked by the user or they have expired.
    print ('The credentials have been revoked or expired, please re-run'
           'the application to re-authorize')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  for i in range(1,2):
      main('loop/credentials_'+str(i)+'.dat')
      print i
```

it works only for single user credential , but for my case I want to get multiple users,  but above code give me only one.

Anybody know how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access multiple calendars of different people, the best way is to create a service account (which will do all requests to API's on behalf of users). So,users are not prompted with consent screen for authentication for accessing their calendar. Here are the steps:

1. Create a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) and you as the admin for the domain.
2. Share all the calendars to this service account.
3. For the service account to access users data, follow [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation) link for
   domain wide delegation.
4. Check this [link](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client) for service account sample code in java. For python guide check this [link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth).

Comment: what you mean on #2 , could you explain more?

Comment: I really need more details or more sample code, if you have it , because I blocked by this problem for a few weeks.

Comment: yea plz,what #2 means?